# Accidentally deleted .xcodeproject file, have been using the built in git back up, but it DID NOT backup that file?

Tags: xcode, git

I have every other file, I have all the `.swift` and `.storyboard` files, all the images, everything! But I have no way to open the overall file since `.xcodeproject` was deleted.

I can roll back to all my past commits, but none of them have saved the `.xcodeproject` for some reason.

I was using the integrated git add, commit, push functionality within xcode and not doing it through terminal as I usually do. Help???

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have backup where do you want to restore the file from?

If you added the file to git (commited or by `git add`) you will be able to restore it, but if you did not added it, no one can help you ...

---

### How to restore added file?

If you did a `git add` on the desired file you can simply search for it and then restore it.

```
# Search for all uncommitted added files = dangling content
git fsck --full

# print out the content of the dangling content
git show <SHA-1>
```

Now if you see your `.xcodeproject` simply copy and save it back into your project.

Comment: Nah so the problem is, I have been using git to back it all up. However, it has been backing up all the files EXCEPT for the .xcodeproject, which is needed to run the actual app.